# Possible deadlock in boost websocket server

Tags: c++, boost

I have boost websocket server and it probably get into the deadlock sometimes, but it happens rarely and I am not sure in which scenario it happens.

code looks like:

```
mutex m_action_lock;
condition_variable m_action_cond;
queue<pair<websocketpp::connection_hdl, server::message_ptr>> m_actions;

void Gateway::on_message(websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg)
{
    logMesaage("Incoming message...", "");

    unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_action_lock);
    m_actions.push(pair<websocketpp::connection_hdl, server::message_ptr> (hdl,msg));
    lock.unlock();

    m_action_cond.notify_one();
}

void Gateway::process_messages()
{
    logMesaage("Start processing messages", "");

    while (1)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_action_lock);

        while (m_actions.empty())
        {
            m_action_cond.wait(lock);
        }

        pair<websocketpp::connection_hdl, server::message_ptr> action = m_actions.front();
        m_actions.pop();

        lock.unlock();

        logMesaage("Received message", "");
    }

    logMesaage("End processing messages", "");
}
```

The normal flow of logged messages should be:

```
Incoming message...
Received message
```

But sometimes it stop working and after I send any message I get logged only:

```
Incoming message...
```

But I do not see any place for deadlock here in this code did you?
Thanks

Comment: Probably not the place where the issue is. Better way to debug such issues it to run `strace` OR/AND get the crash dump (`kill -11` in linux) when you think your process is stuck and analyze it.

Comment: Also, as a side note, I am assuming that you are using zaphoyd/websocketpp ? My personal opinion would be to try using some simpler websocket library. Not that I have anything against it, but I feel its a bit over engineered and thus would be difficult to find issues in it (if at all).

Comment: @Arunmu thanks, I will try to run strace on it when it happens. And yop I am using websocketpp for ssl websocket and and some other communication. It appears quite simple to me in that time...